# Entity framework memory not released

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using a very simple asp.net mvc application with Entity Framework 6.0.2, .Net 4.5.1:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
      int count;
      using (var db = new LocalContext())
      {
         count = db.Counters.Count();
      }
      return View(count);
   }
}

public class Counter
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class LocalContext : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<Counter> Counters { get; set; }
}
```

If I do a load test on it, I eventually get an Out Of Memory Exception. (`tinyget -srv:localhost -port:<port> -uri:/home/index/ -threads:30 -loop:5000`). In Performance monitor I see the generation 2 Heap steadily grow. If I use a smaller loop value (say 500), the size grows until tinyget stops. Then the heap size stays the same (for at least 20 minutes, after that I stopped the server).

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

So I tried Simon Mouriers suggestion and left out the EF code. Then I don't have memory problems. So I thought, maybe if I use Release instead of Debug, it will make a difference. And it did! Memory was released after a while and I could put high load on the site. Then I switched back to Debug to see if I could get more info and... even in Debug mode no problems anymore. FML, I worked a day on it and now I can't reproduce it anymore.

Comment: I'd say your not doing anything wrong, more than likely this is a problem with EF's over-bloated codebase.

Comment: I can't find anything wrong either, I just think it's very strange the memory usage isn't going down.

Comment: Presumably replacing the code with `int count = 0; return View(count);` doesn't demonstrate the problem which suggests its EF not something else?

Comment: You might have stumbled upon a bug in EF 6, try to downgrade to EF 5. If you can confirm this to be a change between EF 5 and 6, I think M$ would be happy to hear from you (ref. http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1605 - last comments)

Comment: I have been testing with fully blown app on EF 6.0.1-21010 (6.0.21010.0) and it seems to grow to certain point and from then on it's stable. I hope this will narrow down the search scope.

Comment: Have you tried the same test simply without this code? This would rule out anything that's not related to EF (server, extension, 3rd party, asp.net app, etc.). Also what's the database you're using? SQL Server?

Comment: What is the type `Counters` is returning ? IEnumerable ?

Comment: Looks like you might be hitting this: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1605

Comment: Have you tried Lazy loading?

Comment: @stames, it looks like it, but I can't seem to reproduce the porblem anymore.

Comment: @rhughes, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: If you do repro it again run ants or something similar on the app and see what is actually taking the memory.

Answer (score 3):

In your case the internally managed class that inherits from DbContext would then need to implement IDisposable and inside of the LocalContext add the following:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    this.Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}

protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
     if (disposing)
     {
        // Manage any native resources.
     }
   //Handle any other cleanup.
}
```

Without specifically overriding the call to dispose, the using statement is only going to call Dispose() against the base class, while you need to dispose of the parent and base.

Comment: This is bad advice. The subclass doesn't introduce any new resources that need to be **additionally** disposed of, the base class' `Dispose` implementation is sufficient. See the section "Deriving from a Disposable Type" in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2007/july/clr-inside-out-digging-into-idisposable

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with your code. Maybe this could be an issue with the underlying ADO.NET provider. Which database are you using?

I remember having issues with some unit test that did not release SQLite database files which I eventually solved with this code (in my DbContext class)

```
public class LocalContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        var connection = this.Database.Connection;
        base.Dispose(disposing);
        connection.Dispose();
    }
}
```

May be unrelated but I would give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the correct answer, but i suggest to keep your context managed by a IoC container. And add it with TrasientScope, or PerHttpRequest scope(example not provided due to a large varierty of ioc container syntax). If you want a specfic example, please reply for what DI you want

Comment: In the code shown the context is scoped per request. This is the simplest example I could come up with, DI would only complicate it in this case.

Comment: Then it must be a resource that isn`t disposed, thus its parents objects are not collected. GC colects only the resources that has no references. You must see what is left undisposed.I preffer to use an IoC container because it does almost all the dirty work for me, this is why i recomanded it to you

Answer (score 0):

I would go for creating a class connection to the DB ..

```
public class DBconnection : IDisposable
{
    private ChatEntities _db = new ChatEntities();

    protected ChatEntities Db {
        get { return _db; }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_db != null)
        {
            _db.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Then when you would like to connect and manipulate .. Lets call it the DBlogic class ..

```
public class DBlogic : DBconnection
{
       internal void WriteToDB(String str){
          //Do something ...

          Db.SaveChanges();
        }
}
```

This will eventually cause the Dispose to empty resources.. plus its cleaner .. at least for my eyes :D

Comment: Your code will close connections to db if it is opened. Nothing else. But the problem is in memory usage of managed memory.

Comment: Yep ,i can see that now .. 

@KirillBestemyanov

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score -2):

Actually, the `OutOfMemotyException` is normal in this situation since the Garbage Collector does not occur immediately after you've finished with the object. In this scenario, you need to use GC.Collect() to perform a collection on all generations of memory and reclaim all memory that is inaccessible, *immediately*.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
      int count;
      using (var db = new LocalContext())
      {
         count = db.Counters.Count();
      }

      GC.Collect();
      return View(count);
   }
}
```

Note that you should not use [GC.Collect()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in production code since it interferes with the Garbage Collection mechanism.

Comment: This is at best treating symptoms and ignoring the underlying problem.  The problem has to be a Dispose pattern issue or some other form of dangling reference.  It could be a bug in EF.  It could even be some obscure issue where .NET itself got sideways.  Note that the OP said that after building Release then switching back to Debug, the issue could not be reproduced.